# How to convert L609 4wire to L6 3wire

Tags: electrical, wiring

My electrical feed to location is L6 3wire (grnd+X+Y). My cabinet is L609 4wire (grnd+neut+X+Y).

The cabinet feeds 4 blocks of 110V.

Should the grnd+neutr be plugged into the grnd on the L6? or do I need to pull a fourth (neut) to the box, and use an L609 receptical?

Grnd and Neut in the wiring cabinet are the same, so I'm wondering if it's really necessary to carry a separate neutral, and thus I can use an L6

Answer (score 1):

There is NO neutral in a NEMA L6-?? circuit. That is a straight 240V circuit/receptacle.

I have no idea what an "L609" is. There is no such NEMA number, but you CANNOT simply run a loose or separate neutral for this circuit. It MUST be run with the circuit conductors in the same cable or conduit/raceway. It must also be correctly sized based on the required circuit and overcurrent protection.

Also, what is the cabinet you speak of? Is this what you are feeding or where the feed comes from??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to run a separate neutral wire. No, you may not fake a neutral or a ground by bridging them at your "cabinet".